# How to capture the definition of a topological space as the fixed point of a function?

Tags: definition

There's an asymmetry between the requirements for intersections and unions in the laws for topological spaces. In the most common presentation of a topological space that I've seen, the space is a pair $(X, \tau)$ with $X$ being the "universe of discourse" (I don't know what the actual term is), and $\tau$ being the set of open sets. I think there's an equivalent one with closed sets that you get by DeMorgan-ing the laws for open sets.

Anyway, I've studied mathematical objects before where you have a set and you insist that it's closed under certain operations. With topological spaces, you have two different closure properties. I think you can in general "translate" between closure-flavored and fixpoint-flavored properties... something like

$$ \text{S is closed under f} \Longleftrightarrow \text{S is a fixed point of } (\lambda x : x \cup \left\{f(t)\;|\;t \in x \right\}) $$

How do you do the same thing for a topological space?

Pretend for a moment that all topological spaces that we consider are topological spaces over a particular set $X$.

The laws for topological spaces ($\tau \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X) $ or equivalently $\tau \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$)  are the following. (I'm not sure whether "law" is the right word here.)

1. $\varnothing \in \tau$
2. $X \in \tau$
3. let $A$ be a finite sequence of elements of $\tau$ of length $n$
   $$ \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right) \in \tau $$
4. let $B \in \mathcal{P}(\tau)$ be an arbitrary element of the powerset of $\tau$.
   $$ \left( \bigcup B \right) \in \tau $$

suppose for a second that we ignore law #2, so we're talking about topological spaces on $X$ or on some subset of $X$.

I want to come up with a function $T : \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X)) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ so that all the fixed points are topological spaces on $X$ (or a subset of $X$).

Here's what I came up with

$$ T : \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X)) \rightarrow  \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$$
   $$ T(\tau) = \left\{ (\cap \; x) \; | \; x \in \mathcal{P}(\tau), \text{x is finite}\right\} \cup \left\{ (\cup \; x) \; | \; x \in \mathcal{P}(\tau) \right\} $$

It's possible to "factor" this function into two functions, since $\psi \subseteq T(\psi)$ for every possible set $\psi$.

$$ T = T_1 \circ T_0 $$

where

$$ T_0(\tau) = \left\{ (\cap \; x) \; | \; x \in \mathcal{P}(\tau), \text{x is finite} \right\} $$

and

$$ T_1(\tau) = \left\{ (\cup \; x) \; | \; x \in \mathcal{P}(\tau)\right\} $$

Suppose I have a function $T'$
  $$ T' = \left\{ f(x,x') \; | \; (x,x') \in \tau \times \tau \right\}$$

In $T'_1$, $f$ is $\cup$. In $T'_0$, $f$ is $\cap$.

Can $T_0$ be replaced with $T'_0$?

Can $T_1$ be replaced with $T'_1$?

I know that both can't be true simultaneously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a family of sets is closed under the map $a, b\mapsto a\cap b$ (that is, individual intersections), then it's easy to show by induction that it's closed under all finite intersections. So $T_0'$ can indeed replace $T_0$.

However, this would *not* work for infinite intersections. And indeed, $T_1$ cannot be replaced by $T_1'$. For an easy example, start with the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. This is closed under $T_1'$, but not under $T_1$, since $\mathbb{N}$ is a union of infinitely many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ but is not a union of *finitely* many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.